# php conditional regex problem

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I'm having a tough time sorthing this out. I'm working with a custom plugin system that presents things like this:

```
<plugin:class:method var1='hello', var2='yes' />
```

But, ':method' and the variables do not have to exist - only the 'class' is required. For instace, this should still be ok:

```
<plugin:class />
```

The problem I'm having is how to I get the regex to conditionally return things when the method and/or variables do not exist. So far, I can get results when all the pieces exist, but not otherwise - this is where I'm at (struggling on the first conditional):

```
$f = "/<plugin:(?P<class>\w+)(?(?=^:)?P<method>\w+)\s+(.*)\/>/sUi";
```

Things are working very well with the following code, it's simply a matter of being able to return all the pieces with the conditionals:

```
preg_replace_callback($f, array($this, 'processing'), $text);
```

Hope this makes some sense - and is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: You are not designing a regular language. use a parser for context-free grammar (yes, I know some regex parsers support recursion … – but it's not the right tool™ for the job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most maintainable way to do this would be to just get the whole `plugin:class:method` string with a simple `/plugin:\S+/` expression, then `explode(':', $string)`.

So, instead of the code above, you'd have something like:

```
$f = "/<plugin:(\S+)\s+(.*?)\/>/sUi";
if (preg_match($f, $string, $matches)) {
    $parts = explode($matches[1]);
    if (!in_array('method', $parts))
    {
        // do whatever needs done if "method" is not present
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: **"most maintable"** - I'd like to know more about this. Is it because I'm using PCRE extended thing that's not available in all situations?

Comment: @telefiend, I'm saying that this would be maintainable because the code will be very easy to read, understand and extend, than a complicated regular expression that would do the same thing. Added example.

Comment: I understand that. I have actually done it your way in the past but thought it might be more easy if the regex was more precise in it's output. A problem of style I suppose - good thing to think about.

Comment: `$f = "/<plugin:(\S+)\s+(.*)\/>/sUi";`


Final solution, as suggested. Keep it simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `(?=^:)` be `(?!:)` ?

Comment: `code`"/<plugin:(?P<class>\w+)(?(?!:)?P<method>\w+)\s+(.*)\/>/sUi"`code` - doesn't do the trick.